# r combine results from multiple lme4 objects

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr, gtsummary

I am running a mixed effects model on my dataset ,

```
   library(lme4)
   data(cake)
```

each dataset is a subset of a larger datsaet

```
    subset(cake, recipe=="A")
    subset(cake, recipe=="B")
    subset(cake, recipe=="C")
```

I am using dlply to run my mixed effects model on each subset

```
   MxM1 <-   plyr::dlply(cake,
                   "recipe",
                     function(x)
                       lmer(angle ~ 1+ (1|replicate)+ temperature,
                          data=x))
```

This gives me a list of summaries based on each subset of data.

I know how to display the summaries one at a time using `gt_summary` package

```
       lm_cake$A %>%
            tbl_regression() %>%
               modify_column_hide(columns = ci) %>%
                  modify_column_unhide(columns = std.error)

   lm_cake$B %>%
            tbl_regression() %>%
               modify_column_hide(columns = ci) %>%
                  modify_column_unhide(columns = std.error)

   lm_cake$B %>%
            tbl_regression() %>%
               modify_column_hide(columns = ci) %>%
                  modify_column_unhide(columns = std.error)
```

I am not sure how to combine the results from all 3 objects (`lm_cake$A`, `lm_cake$B`, `lm_cake$C`) to display them as one summary table.

```
                Model: A                    Model: B           Model: C    
    Temperature            Beta    SE       Beta    SE       Beta    SE
        Temperature. L   
        Temperature. Q   
        Temperature. C   
        Temperature^4   
        Temperature^5
```

Any suggestions or help is much apricated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also merge two or more gtsummary tables using the `gtsummary::tbl_merge()` function. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #StandWithUkraine
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
data(cake)

MxM1 <- 
  plyr::dlply(
    cake,
    "recipe",
    function(x) {
      lmer(angle ~ 1+ (1|replicate)+ temperature, data=x) %>%
        tbl_regression() %>%
        modify_column_hide(columns = ci) %>%
        modify_column_unhide(columns = std.error)
    }
  )

# Merge all model summaries together with `tbl_merge()` 
tbl <-
MxM1 %>%
  tbl_merge(
    tab_spanner = c("**A**", "**B**", "**C**")
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-12-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Great! FYI, there are `tbl_stack()` and `tbl_strata()` functions that could be helpful in similar situations. Actually, `tbl_strata()` could have solved this even more efficiently!

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
While the answer by @Daniel D. Sjoberg is perfect and the desired one. Here is the answer to OP's question in the comments:
"How can i convert the final results from long format to wide, by each recipe?"

After filtering `temperature` we could use `pivot_wider` and some tweaking thereafter:

Note we have to use `broom.mixed` package for our `lmer`

```
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)
#library(broom)
library(broom.mixed)

cake %>% 
  mutate(recipe = as_factor(recipe)) %>% 
  group_by(recipe) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = function(df){
    lmer(angle ~ 1 + (1|replicate) + temperature,
         data=df) %>% 
      tidy() %>% 
      add_column(recipe = unique(df$recipe), .before = 1)
  }) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(term, "temperature")) %>%
  select(recipe, term, Beta=estimate, SE = std.error) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = recipe,
              values_from = c(Beta, SE)) %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_replace(., "(.*)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1"), -1) %>% 
  select(term, sort(colnames(.)))
```

```
  term          A_Beta  A_SE B_Beta  B_SE C_Beta  C_SE
  <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 temperature.L  6.43   1.22  6.88   1.16  6.52   1.12
2 temperature.Q -0.713  1.22 -0.946  1.16  0.502  1.12
3 temperature.C -2.33   1.22  0.368  1.16  0.313  1.12
4 temperature^4 -3.35   1.22 -0.328  1.16 -0.214  1.12
5 temperature^5 -0.151  1.22 -0.815  1.16 -1.78   1.12
```

**First answer:**
You need something like this?:

```
library(lme4)
data(cake)

library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(broom.mixed)

cake %>% 
  mutate(recipe = as_factor(recipe)) %>% 
  group_by(recipe) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = function(df){
    lmer(angle ~ 1 + (1|replicate) + temperature,
         data=df) %>% 
  tidy() %>% 
  add_column(recipe = unique(df$recipe), .before = 1)
  })
```

```
 A tibble: 24 × 7
   recipe effect   group     term            estimate std.error statistic
   <fct>  <chr>    <chr>     <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 A      fixed    NA        (Intercept)       33.1        1.42    23.3  
 2 A      fixed    NA        temperature.L      6.43       1.22     5.26 
 3 A      fixed    NA        temperature.Q     -0.713      1.22    -0.583
 4 A      fixed    NA        temperature.C     -2.33       1.22    -1.90 
 5 A      fixed    NA        temperature^4     -3.35       1.22    -2.74 
 6 A      fixed    NA        temperature^5     -0.151      1.22    -0.124
 7 A      ran_pars replicate sd__(Intercept)    5.16      NA       NA    
 8 A      ran_pars Residual  sd__Observation    4.73      NA       NA    
 9 B      fixed    NA        (Intercept)       31.6        1.81    17.5  
10 B      fixed    NA        temperature.L      6.88       1.16     5.93 
# … with 14 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: I think you can simplify your `map_dfr` expression a little bit to `map_dfr(lmer, formula = angle ~ 1 + (1|replicate) + temperature)` (untested)

Comment: @TarJae, how can i convert the final results from long format to wide, by each `recipe`

Comment: @BenBolker, I replaced TarJae map_dfr(...) with your solution and i get an error , 'Error in dplyr::bind rows(), Argument 1 must be a dataf rame or a name atomic vector`